# why user space atomic_t in gcc(3.4.5) doesn't work

Tags: c, concurrency

Recently in my work, I want to implement a counter in a multi-thread program. I find there is a user space data type named **atomic_t** in my GCC(3.4.5). But it seems not real atomic.

I tested **atomic_inc()/atomic_read()** on a x86_64 machine with 12 cores and linux kernel is 2.6.9.

This is the demo. I add pthread_cond_t and pthread_cond_broadcast to increase the degree of concurrency.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <asm/atomic.h>

atomic_t atomic_count;
pthread_cond_t g_cond;
pthread_mutex_t g_mutex;

void* thread_func(void*p) {
    pthread_mutex_t* lock = (pthread_mutex_t*)p;
    pthread_mutex_lock(lock);
    pthread_cond_wait(&g_cond, lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(lock);

    for (int i=0;i<20000;++i){
        atomic_inc(&atomic_count);
    }
    return NULL;
}
#define THRD_NUM 15

int main() {
    atomic_set(&atomic_count, 0);
    pthread_cond_init(&g_cond, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&g_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_t pid[THRD_NUM];

    for (int i=0; i<THRD_NUM; i++) {
        pthread_create(&pid[i], NULL, thread_func, &g_mutex);
    }

    sleep(3);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&g_cond);

    for (int i=0; i<THRD_NUM; i++) {
        pthread_join(pid[i], NULL);
    }

    long ans = atomic_read(&atomic_count);
    printf("atomic_count:%ld \n", ans);
}
```

The expected result is 300000, but we always get 270000+ or 280000+ instead. 
I found the implementation of **atomic_inc()** is

```
 static __inline__ void atomic_inc(atomic_t *v)
 {
     __asm__ __volatile__(
         LOCK "incl %0"
         :"=m" (v->counter)
         :"m" (v->counter));
 }
```

According to intel manual, the *LOCK* prefix has the semantic of full barrier. Is that means the program's output has nothing to do with instruction reorder?

What is more, I found an interesting phenomenon. If I set the **THRD_NUM** less then 12(my machine's core number), the error will be in less frequency. I think it may be caused by context switch. But I have no idea how this happened. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: since you `pthread_mutex_unlock()` before your thread has finished running the loop, it opens the possibility that multiple threads(on multiple cores) are simultaneously trying to increment the same variable. So it all sorts of **[readers-writers problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem)**. Also additional complexity is involved when multiple threads are scheduled on the same CPU and one pre-empts the other. Consider using memory fences.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist isn't atomic _supposed_ to mean it get completed without being pre-empted. The atomic operators are supposed to lock the memory bus meaning no locks are required per thread. Am I mis-understanding something?

Comment: Simple naming a function "Atomic" does not disable pre-emption, neither does the `LOCK` prefix. According to the **[Intel System Programming Guide](http://download.intel.com/design/processor/manuals/253668.pdf#page=329&zoom=auto,67,209)**, on modern P6 CPUs, there is a concept of "cache-locking" wherein the memory bus may NOT be asserted by the CPU if the object being referenced in entirely contained in a cache-line.

Comment: Consider the scenario where CPUs both have read the `atomic_count` into their L1 cache and multiple threads on each are happily churning away incrementing their copies. Eventually both of the caches will be flushed and the one that makes it first would be lost. I do agree that all this is completely hypothetical and pure conjecture on my part and worth hogwash. Tools like the **[Advisor XE in Intel parallel studio](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-advisor-xe)** help visualise exactly whats happening in such situations.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: You've missed the part where it says that the processor will use its cache coherency mechanisms to ensure that the operation completes atomically.

Comment: hmmm... i guess i better run the visualiser/inspector myself and try and "see"  what is **actually** happening that we lose those 10-15% increment cmds...

Comment: I recommend disassembling your binary and posting a link to the results.  This behavior is very unusual and it's not out of the question that it's a compiler bug, especially since you are using such an ancient compiler.  GCC 3.4.5 is from 2005... that's old!

Comment: FWIW, i gave it a try. Removed the kernel header #include and locally defined the required atomic structure and functions - **[atomic-test.c](https://gist.github.com/TheCodeArtist/6082246)** Its working fine and producing expected output. @user2612754 Can you compile [atomic-test.c](https://gist.github.com/TheCodeArtist/6082246) using gcc3.4.5 and test on your machine?...

Comment: Built using gcc4.6.3 and tested on a 4core Intel PC. As its written without any compiler intrinsics, ideally one should be able to build it using older gcc as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOCK is a macro. Are you sure it's actually defined to "lock" as it should be to actually do anything?

I'm pretty sure you're using headers that are for the kernel only. Stuff under "asm" shouldn't be used in userland.

Comment: Since he/she included asm/atomic.h LOCK should be defined properly. There is usually no issue with using non-privilege  kernel calls in userland. One downside is some architectures don't have easy atomic operations, for example sparc uses an ugly spin lock.

Comment: `LOCK` (`LOCK_PREFIX` in later kernels) is defined based on `CONFIG_SMP` -- if SMP is not set, then it's a noop.  The OP *might* be able to make this work by adding `-DCONFIG_SMP` to his compiler flags, but I wouldn't bet on it, as asm/atomic.h is designed for use in the kernel, not in user space.

Comment: @ScottyBauer There's no problem using the instructions in userland. But kernel headers are written for the particular kernel environment with whatever defines and compiler flags that the kernel has. The header may or may not work in userland. And it may or may not work or even exist next week. It's just bad practice to use kernel headers, macros and inline functions in userland.

Comment: @Art  Problem solved! I add -DCONFIG_SMP to compiler flags and it is working correctly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I assume `<asm/atomic.h>` is some Linux kernel header?  It's certainly not part of C.  [In C11 there are atomics that you get through `<stdatomic.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).  You'd need to switch to a newer gcc though.

I don't know where you're getting the `LOCK` macro from, but I don't think it is defined correctly.  In [the version of Linux's asm/atomic.h I find with a Google search](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h) they are using a macro called `LOCK_PREFIX`, not `LOCK`.

Here's their code for atomic_inc:

```
93 static inline void atomic_inc(atomic_t *v)
94 {
95         asm volatile(LOCK_PREFIX "incl %0"
96                      : "+m" (v->counter));
97 }
```

This should just turn into:

```
asm volatile("lock incl %0"
             : "+m" (v->counter));
```

I'd stop bothering with the macros and just put the string in (`"lock incl %0"`).

Then compile `gcc -S myfile.c` and make sure that in `myfile.s` you see the `lock incl` instruction and not just a plain `incl` (with no `lock`).

Answer (score -3):

I believe

```
atomic_t atomic_count;
```

Should be

```
volatile atomic_t atomic_count;
```

Try that.

Comment: I looked the online gcc manuals @ http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.6/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html and it does not specify volatile. May I know how you came across this? The assembly code for atomic_inc does have asm __volatile. Please clarify while I look into the Intel manual.

Comment: Well, the assembly is __Volatile__ meaning the compiler can't rearrange the assembly within that statement. The volatility of a variable does not change the place in which a variable is stored. What it changes is the semantics around how it is accessed with respect to reads and writes. Many of the bugs I've run into while doing multi thread stuff was the fact I didn't declare volatile variables, so it was my first hunch. Whether it worked or not for him, I don't know. I guess I could compile it.

Comment: `volatile` simply does not belong here.  Please see [Volatile: Almost Useless for Multi-Threaded Programming](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming) by Arch Robison.

Comment: Well, I don't think volatile has barrier semantics in c/c++. Actually,  the type atomic_t is a volatile int.